# Custom login page for Spring Security with WebFlux and OAuth2 (oauth2Login)

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

On `Spring Security 5.1.4` with a **WebFlux** application and **OAuth2** enabled I'm not finding any means to override the default login page generated for `/login`. I was used to simply create a controller for `/login` however the controller is not hit.

The only "solution" I found so far is setting the `httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(...)`

and to my surprise the login controller starts to work, as this prevents `LoginPageSpec` to generate `LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter`.

Are there any facilities that are intended to be used to override the login page in such a setup?

```
var httpSecurity =
    http.authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .authenticationConverter(tokenConverter)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutHandler(new KeycloakLogoutHandler(serverOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository()))
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
        .logoutUrl("/sso/logout")
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
        .and()
        .build();
```